# Gatekeeper permission issue

Tags: gatekeeper

I installed Acronis True Image 2018, but unable to install the drivers due to permission issues.

Also I have tried the below

```
Vivek’s MacBook Pro:~ vivek$ sudo xattr -cr /Applications/Acronis\ True\ Image.app
Vivek’s MacBook Pro:~ vivek$ sudo codesign -f -s - /Applications/Acronis\ True\ Image.app
Password:
/Applications/Acronis True Image.app: replacing existing signature
/Applications/Acronis True Image.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Applications/Acronis True Image.app/Contents/MacOS/acronis_drive.config
Vivek’s MacBook Pro:~ vivek$ sudo codesign -f -s /Applications/Acronis\ True\ Image.app
error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
Vivek’s MacBook Pro:~ vivek$ sudo codesign -f -s - /Applications/Acronis\ True\ Image.app
/Applications/Acronis True Image.app: replacing existing signature
/Applications/Acronis True Image.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Applications/Acronis True Image.app/Contents/MacOS/acronis_drive.config
Vivek’s MacBook Pro:~ vivek$ sudo codesign -f -s - /Applications/Acronis\ True\ Image.app
Password:
/Applications/Acronis True Image.app: replacing existing signature
```

This has not helped either, I have tried to contact the Acronis support team and they couldn't help either.I also tried to disable the system policy and trying to allow apps from anywhere

[image: I've unlocked and clicked 'Allow' as well, no success!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need temporary disable SIP (boot yo single mode by press CMD and R when reboot the system). Run the Terminal and enter

`csrutil disable`

Reboot and reinstall, in your screenshot, allow it!

Comment: I was reluctant to try this option, but it did solve it! Thanks